# How to Create Typescript template project

Tags: javascript, typescript

Any references or links on How to create a Typescript Template project similar to Dotnet template projects.

What I want to achieve is to create a template, so that anyone who needs to consume can install the template on local machine which would fetch the source code from github.

I am trying to build something similar to react template. But cannot find any references. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make code generator or something similar?

Maybe this would help:
https://yeoman.io/learning/

Comment: nope I need something similar to dotnet new

Comment: But Dotnet new just does what yeoman does